# Locks between two methods starving one method

Tags: java, file-io, concurrency, synchronization

In my program i have two methods:

```
public void methodA() { //gets called very often
   //write something to file
}

public void methodB() {
  //write something to file
}
```

`methodA` gets called by the client very often, whereas `methodB` gets only called from time to time. However, I need to make sure that whenever a client wants to call `methodB` it can do so (after possible current execution of `methodA` has finished). I tried to introduce a synchronized block with an locking object within each method however `methodB` seems to starve, since `methodA` gets called more often.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: use executor framework

Comment: can you not use semaphores to protect the calls ?

Comment: what's kind of dependency between two methods?

Comment: Did you consider reentrant locks? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like you are in need of a **fair** `Lock`. To make one of these you should pass `true` as a parameter to the constructor.

```
Lock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);

public void methodA() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        // Write something to a file.
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

public void methodB() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        // Write something to a file.
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. How does solution 1 ensure that methodB does not starve? If I use locks according to your first solution the behavior is the same. As methodA gets called very often, not all calls of methodB are successfull

Comment: @user1291235 - Using the fair lock option (passing `true` to the constructor) gives priority to the longest waiting thread and should avoid starvation.

Comment: Ugh. This is one of those circumstances where having keyword parameters would enhance readability by a lot... `ReentrantLock(fair=true)` doesn't require knowing the API by heart in order to understand what the code is doing. In absence of this it's probably better to comment about that lonely and meaningless `true`.

Comment: @Bakuriu - I feel your pain - I would use something like `enum Strategy{Fast,Fair}` but that would not be backwards compatible.

Comment: @Bakuriu I have occasionbally experimented with the idea of declaring constants: `FairLock = true` `FastLock=false`. Then calling the method as follows: `new ReentrantLock(FairLock)` (In places where I've used it: it has improved readability, but it might also increase the chance of errors if you accidentally get the constant values wrong.)

Comment: I usually write something like `new ReentrantLock( /* fair: */ true )`.

Answer (score 2):

`ReentrantLock` has a [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#ReentrantLock(boolean)) with a fairness parameter that should prevent starvation in your case.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prioritize methodB over methodA, this is the simplest thing I could come up with:

```
private Object writeLock = new Object();
private Object highPriorityLock = new Object();
private int highPriorityLockReleaseCount = 0;
private int highPriorityLockLockCount = 0;

public void methodA() {
    synchronized (writeLock) {
        synchronized (highPriorityLock) {
            // Wait until there are no more highPriorityLocks
            while (highPriorityLockLockCount != highPriorityLockReleaseCount) {
                highPriorityLock.wait();
            }
        }
        // Do write (thread holds write lock)
    }
}

public void methodB() {
    synchronized (highPriorityLock) {
        // Get current lock count
        int lockCount = highPriorityLockLockCount;
        // Increment lock count by one
        highPriorityLockLockCount++;
        // Wait until lock is acquired (current release count reaches saved lock count)
        while (lockCount != highPriorityLockReleaseCount) {
            highPriorityLock.wait();
        }
    }
    synchronized (writeLock) {
        // Do write (thread holds write lock)
    }
    synchronized (highPriorityLock) {
        // Relase high priority lock by incrementing current counter
        highPriorityLockReleaseCount++;
        highPriorityLock.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Be sure to handle exceptions and to make sure, that high priority lock is always released properly

Comment: What is the initial state of the instance variables? Is it me or it just seems an overkill to use **two** monitor locks, **nesting** them, and **two** access counters for addressing this problem?!

Comment: I think initial values should be obvious, if you understand the algorithm. Wheter it is overkill, depends what your requirements are. It might be that simple ReentrantLock is enough, but I could not determinate that from given requirements.

Comment: Nesting two locks really ring's that deadlock bell for me. Beware.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest envolving a queue with priority. Simply, two queues, one for methodA and another for methodB. Another thread working on the queue in the logic below: when queue for B is not empty, operate it, otherwise, do queue for A.

Comment: No need for two queues. A single one for both methods is sufficient as it gives the same guarantee of progress as the "fair" lock mentioned in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [semaphores](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/semaphores.html) for this. It basically works on the idea that you set a field to some value .. lets say locked. and on the other method you make a while.. which repeats infinite untill the other process finished.  You can use semaphores by calling the method in a diffirent thread.. and use the keyword synchronized void..

Semaphores are partly hardware partly software solutions. There are also pure software solutions out. for example [Peterson's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

If your major concern is with `methodB` call not to be **blocked** or starved you could let the concurrent issues be solved by **non-blocking I/O operations**.

Java NIO.2 [java.nio.channels.AsynchronousFileChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html) can provide for such needs. You can find a good usage explanation and example [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/nio/channels/asynchronousfilechannel/java-nio-channels-asynchronousfilechannel-example/).

Answer (score 0):

This is roughly the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666610/how-to-give-priority-to-privileged-thread-in-mutex-locking). The top rated answer for that question gives three options. Options 2 and 3 both assume that `methodB` will always be called from the same thread, which you haven't said is the case, but option 1 should work. Option 1 ported to Java is:

```
private final Lock m = new ReentrantLock();
private final Lock n = new ReentrantLock();
private final Lock l = new ReentrantLock();

public void methodA() {
    l.lock();
    n.lock();
    m.lock();
    n.unlock();
    try {
        doA();
    } finally {
        m.unlock();
        l.unlock();
    }
}

public void methodB() {
    n.lock();
    m.lock();
    n.unlock();
    try {
        doB();
    } finally {
        m.unlock();
    }
}
```

This gives methodB absolute priority over methodA, unlike OldCurmudgeon's answer, which gives both equal priority. If you also want the algorithm to be fair (apart from the priority of `methodB` over `methodA`), you should make locks `n` and `l` fair. The fairness of `m` is not important.