# How to assign priority in multiple threads in swi-Prolog

Tags: multithreading, swi-prolog, thread-priority

I am working on a project in Prolog where a thread is running the GUI and few threads (say 10) are running in background. All background threads are adding elements to a list. Now if some request comes from GUI, the system needs to show an element from the list.

My approach is that all background threads will apply for a lock to the list. The thread acquiring the lock will starts its execution. If a request comes from GUI, it will also apply for lock and wait for the current thread to finish the work. My problem is how to assign priority to GUI thread so that once the current thread leaves the lock, only GUI will get the lock and not the other 9 threads who have applied for locks.

Comment: You can't do that with a simple lock. You could emulate priority locks as [shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666610/how-to-give-priority-to-privileged-thread-in-mutex-locking) but using a priority queue would be a lot simpler