# Give access to a resource based on thread priority/privilege

Tags: c++, pthreads

I am not a developer, I'm just playing with programming by trying to make my workplace more autonomous.
I am currently trying to get a range of 9 threads with all different priorities (0: highest 8: lowest) to use the same UART port.

As I have to send emergency request I'd to create a lock that allow the highest priority thread to go first on the resource.

I also have to let the receive_data IRQ thread get the hand on the UART port as soon as it occur(or as soon as possible, hardware UART buffer is 500 bytes long).

I have been looking around and using nested mutex is going to prevent me to make the code evolve if I need more priority levels/thread (or at least will need a fair amount of coding).

I've read this question : [How to give priority to privileged thread in mutex locking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666610/how-to-give-priority-to-privileged-thread-in-mutex-locking) and the second answer looks like what I wish for...but I cant understand how to implement the process.

As the question is a bit old, is there another way to do what I want?
If not, can I get a more readable version of it (woodworker)?

Question: How to protect the access to the UART reader/writer & give priority access to thread based on their priority level?

Note:

Threads are currently reading one fifo each and are sleeping while the fifo is empty and start when something is put in their respective fifo.

Threads then process the command/data in a format that can be interpreted by the hardware and sent via UART.

I try to do that as I realized that sometimes emergency commands where waiting ~1s or more before being processed when I was using a single thread and the fifo was heavily populated.

Also, sorry if my English is giving you goose bump.

Comment: Please re-frame your question to give better clarity on what you are asking.

Comment: This is a pretty non-trivial bit of work. The linked question does seem to have multiple examples of code that would be a great starting point (or complete solution), and if you can't make use of that you might want to reconsider your design to simplify things until you can make something that works, and move to a more sophisticated system later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments its a complicated task.

One way to do it will be to create a class like this one:

```
class UART_access_manager

{

typedef std::multimap<int, dispatch_semaphore_t> priority_map_t;
public:

 UART_access_manager();
~UART_access_manager();
void access_manager(unsigned int prio, dispatch_semaphore_t pSem);


private:

void amInext(unsigned int prio);
void process_priority(unsigned int prio);
void priority_locker(unsigned int prio);
void priority_unlocker(unsigned int prio);


int count;
std::mutex data_mtx, priority_0_mtx, mtx;
priority_map_t priority_map;
};
```

note I build the test on OSX and un-named semaphore can't be used, I didn't check if dispatch is available on other OS (probably not as its an apple lib).

```
UART_access_manager::UART_access_manager()

{

}
UART_access_manager::~UART_access_manager()
{

}



 /*********************************************************************
  *
  * Function:        void UART_access_manager::access_manager(unsigned

int prio, dispatch_semaphore_t pSem)
 *
 * Description:     add an UART access request to the queue based on priority & start process based on type
 *
 * Notes:           0 is highest
 *
 * Returns:         none
 *
 *********************************************************************/

void UART_access_manager::access_manager(unsigned int prio, dispatch_semaphore_t pSem)//, add parameters at will
 {
 int counter = 1; //debug only
 while (counter) //should check for termination criteria
 {
    //check if something was pushed on the file descriptor

    if( counter == 10) //add run condition
    {
        counter = 0; //debug

        priority_locker(prio);

        priority_map_t::iterator it = priority_map.insert(std::pair<int, dispatch_semaphore_t>(prio, pSem) );
        printf("\n thread with priority %d added to queue(size %lu)", prio, priority_map.size());
        amInext(prio);

        priority_unlocker(prio);

        while(dispatch_semaphore_wait(pSem, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW) != 0){};



        priority_locker(prio);
        // do the actual job
        process_priority(prio);
        // done, remove yourself
        priority_map.erase(it);
        if( ! priority_map.empty() )
        {
            // let next guy run:
            dispatch_semaphore_signal((priority_map.begin()->second));
        }
        priority_unlocker(prio);
    }
    else
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50)); //test purpose only
        counter++;
    }

 }
}


/*********************************************************************
 *
 * Function:       void UART_access_manager::amInext(unsigned int prio)
 *
 * Description:    check if current priority has to run next or not
 *
 * Notes:           0 is highest
 *
 * Returns:        none
 *
 *********************************************************************/
 void UART_access_manager::amInext(unsigned int prio)
{

 if(priority_map.begin()->first == prio) dispatch_semaphore_signal(priority_map.begin()->second);
}


/*********************************************************************
*
* Function:        void UART_access_manager::process_priority(unsigned 
int prio)
*
* Description: TODO
*********************************************************************/
void UART_access_manager::process_priority(unsigned int prio)
{
 printf("\n    Priority_%d running \n",prio);
 //TODO
}

/*********************************************************************
*
* Function:       void UART_access_manager::priority_locker(unsigned 
int prio)
*
 * Description:     lock mutex in a way to guarantee priority event 
 to 
 *                  get the fastest lock possible
 *
 * Notes:           0 is highest
 ******************************************************************/
 void UART_access_manager::priority_locker(unsigned int prio)
 {
 //Low-priority threads: lock mtx, lock priority_0_mtx, lock data_mtx, 
  unlock priority_0_mtx,
 //High-priority thread: lock priority_0_mtx, lock data_mtx, unlock 
  priority_0_mtx,
  //this will insure that max priority level get privileged access to 
 the data

if(!prio)
 {
    priority_0_mtx.lock();
    data_mtx.lock();
    priority_0_mtx.unlock();
 }
else
 {
    mtx.lock();
    priority_0_mtx.lock();
    data_mtx.lock();
    priority_0_mtx.unlock();
 }
}

/*********************************************************************
 *
 * Function:        void 
 UART_access_manager::priority_unlocker(unsigned int prio)
 *
 * Description:     unlock mtx based on the mutex locked by the 
 priority level
 *
 * Notes:           0 is highest
 *
 * Returns:         none
 *
 *********************************************************************/
void UART_access_manager::priority_unlocker(unsigned int prio)
{
if(!prio)
 {
    data_mtx.unlock();
 }
else
 {
    mtx.unlock();
    data_mtx.unlock();
 }
}
```

Code is verbose to be easy to understand, and will do nothing as it, you are progressing nicely, see it as a assignment, if you have any question don't hesitate to comment, I'll reply.

(HS: what are you trying to do ?)

Things you'll learn:
std::multimap
std::mutex
semaphores
classes

Comment: Tried, changed it a bit as you said and it works perfectly. Will dig a bit more into it.