# C++ mutex locking thread priority

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, mutex

I'm looking to give priority to a thread so that if two threads are waiting for a mutex, the thread with the highest priority will always take the mutex before the lower priority one.

A colleague suggested that by changing the thread priority of my thread I should achieve that. I tried using the `SetThreadPriority()` function to set one of the waiting threads to 0(normal) and the other one to 2 (highest) but it doesn't affect the mutex behavior like I was hoping. The lock currently always goes to the first thread that requested the ownership.

So is this behavior normal? Contrary to what my colleague thought? Is there a different way to give thread priority that I might be missing? Or am I looking at a more complicated problem to solve?

Comment: My question refers directly to if thread priority (defined by SetThreadPriority()) has an impact on mutex priority which the question you are referring to doesn't seem to do. Even though they are similar, I don't believe they answer quite the same thing.

Comment: Hmm.. sorry then. It certainly answers this one: "I'm looking to give priority to a thread so that if two threads are waiting for a mutex, the thread with the highest priority will always take the mutex before the lower priority one."

Comment: Yeah, I do agree, my next step was definitely to look at questions like the one you mentioned. I was just trying to confirm that thread priority itself wasn't a factor first.

Comment: Rare luck, you've got 2 questions answered in one Q&A! ;)

Comment: However, I would also add that in case of 2 threads this problem definition does not make much sense at all. The probability that both threads request lock at the very same "moment" is minuscule. One thread will always be ahead of another, meaning that there is only 1 thread that competes for the lock at a given nanosecond. That means that no matter what priority is, it will get the lock. For 3 and more threads it makes a bit more sense because there will be more chance for the direct competition: some threads will be waiting in the "queue", while others can bypass.

Comment: Oh yeah, the actual way this will be used is with much more threads with high priority ones skipping ahead of low priority ones. It was just to simplify the question. I'll look at the other question to try to understand better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146446/discussion-between-lhbortho-and-drop).

Comment: I've re-opened, because unlike [the nominal duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666610/how-to-give-priority-to-privileged-thread-in-mutex-locking) this question is specifically about Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread priority says how much time the thread gets on the CPU as determined by the scheduler, which will preferentially schedule higher priority threads - it doesn't affect the behaviour of mutexes, and I'm not aware of any means of making it do so.

Answer (score 0):

Normally mutex are not biased. This can be implemented as a improvised mutex, which is biased with priority, as well manage starvation.