# Cannot delete files after creating them myself on FAT32

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, posix, embedded-linux

I have a program (written in C11, POSIX.1-2008 conform and running on an embedded Linux) which periodically creates files and after some time deletes them again.

When the files are created and removed (both by my program) on an EXT4 filesystem, everything works like a charm.

The interesting thing now happens when a FAT32 filesystem is used: while the program is able to write the files, when it tries to remove them again it kind of freezes. The kind of freezes is that the corresponding process halts, but does not exit and when using a program like top to see the utilisation like VIRT, RES, SHR, %CPU, %MEM all at zero. The same thing happens to a sibling process which communicates with the process which tries to delete the files through FIFOs. The parent process remains active. Also, the file deletion happens in a separate thread of the process, so it should not stop the whole process. The parent process is launched as a deamon, this might be why the two children stay visible in top.

```
                                           |--------------|
                                           |Parent process|
                                           |--------------|
                                                  |
                       ---------------------------|---------------
                      ||                                         ||
                      \/                                         ||
|--------------------------------------------|                   ||
|     Process containing file deletion       |                   \/
||--------------------| |-------------------||             |-------------|
||File deletion thread| |Main process thread|| <- FIFOs -> |Other process|
||--------------------| |-------------------||             |-------------|
|--------------------------------------------|
```

The behaviour does not change if the directory on FAT32 is created beforehand (in the console, on a different PC or however) or by the program itself using

```
mkdir(path, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH)
```

I do check for the return values of all functions but do not detect any anomaly. The remove call operates on the absolute file name.

I can delete the files without any problems in the console (but the program remains halted).

The program runs as root.

Has anyone an idea why I have this behaviour?

Here is the code that runs in the file deletion thread:

```
void* _histDeleteFilesThread(void* context)
{
HistCollection* collection = ((HistThreadContext*)context)->collection;
int* retVal = ((HistThreadContext*)context)->retVal;
free(context);
*retVal = -1;
bool finished = false;

if(collection == NULL){
    logging(stderr, "Bad input to runner thread\n");
    pthread_exit(retVal);
}
else{
    if(pthread_mutex_lock(collection->startNewSearch) != 0){
        logging(stderr, "Failed to lock mutex to start a new search\n");
        pthread_exit(retVal);
    }
    else if(sem_wait(collection->canDeleteFiles) != 0){
        pthread_mutex_unlock(collection->startNewSearch);
        logging(stderr, "Failed to acquire semaphore to delete files\n");
        pthread_exit(retVal);
    }

    while(!finished){
        if(pthread_mutex_lock(collection->fileDeletionDataAccess) != 0){
            sem_post(collection->canDeleteFiles);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(collection->startNewSearch);
            logging(stderr, "Failed to acquire file deletion data access mutex\n");
            pthread_exit(retVal);
        }

        char* file_to_delete;

        if((file_to_delete = _histFIFOPop(&collection->fileToRemove)) == NULL){
            finished = true;
            *collection->fileDeletionThreadRunning = false;
        }
        else{
            char* full_file_name = _histFileCreateAbsolutePath(collection, file_to_delete);
            if(remove(full_file_name) != 0){
                logging(stderr, "Failed to delete file %s\n", full_file_name);
                finished = true;
                *collection->fileDeletionThreadRunning = false;
            }
            else{
                logging(stdout, "Removed %s\n", full_file_name);
            }
            free(full_file_name);
            free(file_to_delete);
        }

        if(pthread_mutex_unlock(collection->fileDeletionDataAccess) != 0){
            sem_post(collection->canDeleteFiles);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(collection->startNewSearch);
            logging(stderr, "Failed to lock mutex to start a new search\n");
            pthread_exit(retVal);
        }
    }

    if(sem_post(collection->canDeleteFiles) != 0){
        pthread_mutex_unlock(collection->startNewSearch);
        logging(stderr, "Failed to lock mutex to start a new search\n");
        pthread_exit(retVal);
    }
    else if(pthread_mutex_unlock(collection->startNewSearch) != 0){
        logging(stderr, "Failed to lock mutex to start a new search\n");
        pthread_exit(retVal);
    }

    *retVal = 0;
    pthread_exit(retVal);
}
```

}

To give a bit of context how the system works: the other process generates data, which is passed to the process containing file deletion through POSIX FIFOs. Inside that process, the data are first buffered in RAM, then written to a file and the file name of this file is then stored in a first SW FIFO. During the time the file is in that first SW FIFO, the data in all files in that SW FIFO plus all the data in the buffer can be searched and used (all searches are in separate threads as they are quite compute intensive and we have to maintain real-time responsiveness). When a file becomes to old, it is moved to a second SW FIFO and the file deletion thread is launched. The thread has to wait until all other searches have terminated before removing the file as otherwise it might still be used by another thread, and no new search can start until the file deletion thread has removed the files in the second SW FIFO (the file deletion thread has a higher run priority (implemented with mutexes and semaphores) to avoid FIFO overflow).

Comment: my first thought is, that whatever this problem is, it has nothing to do with the underlying filesystem... userspace shouldn't/doesn't care about that (except perhaps for corner cases, I think FAT16 only supports file sizes up to 4Gb). Have you tried creating a bare bones MCVE that replicates this problem?

Comment: I would guess this is because of some quirk in a API function rather than anything else. If you can't create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then perhaps you could at least list all relevant functions used by the program(s)? Then with some luck, maybe some Linux guru will be able to pin-point the problem.

Comment: @yano
I would think the same but it is the only difference between the two systems. I thought about that but it is difficult because the whole program (10k LOC) is a real time application where the other process controls some hardware, reads from it and passes data through the FIFOs to the process containing file deletion, where the file deletion thread is launched asynchronously after some (quite complex) criterion are met.

Comment: any chance file handles are still open elsewhere? You say file deletion is launched asynchronously, maybe the timing is just so that you've only seen it on the FAT32 system, but the underlying problem exists on both systems. Is it the exact same binary running on both systems? Different compilers and compiler flags can cause UB to manifest itself in different ways.

Comment: Do you have to run as root?  Doing so is dangerous and should be avoided whenever possible.  However, it is unlikely to be a factor in your problem.

Comment: Ownership and permissions are determined by the uid,gid options in the mount command since they aren't supported by FAT.  If root mounts the drive then a regular user may not be able to make changes.

Comment: @yano
The executable, kernel and rootfs are all the same (created by the same yocto run), only the filesystem changes.
I thought about having timing problems, but as it works for months like a charm on the one sort of system and crashes on the first file deletion on the other sort of system makes me thinks timing and also still open file handles shouldn't be the issue. I implemented an algorithm similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666610/how-to-give-priority-to-privileged-thread-in-mutex-locking to assure correct access to the files (the algorithm has been reviewed by collegues)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler
I do agree on having processes run as root is bad, but 1. the system is still under development (mostly finished though as we only check for stability now) and 2. I have to access UIO devices (which I also could do by changing the access permissions for the corresponding device).

Comment: @stark
I thought about the same, but as root mounts the partition and runs the executable, there should be no issues. Plus if it was a read only filesystem (for example), already the writes of the files should fail and not only when I try to delete them again.

Comment: @Lundin
Which functions would you consider relevant? I use functions for creation, deletion, locking and release of mutexes and semaphorese (to control the access to the actual data between threads); fopen, fclose, fwrite, fflush to create files, remove to delete them and mmap to read them when used.

Comment: @njg Probably all file handling functions, C standard and *nix-specific ones both. As it turns out, these functions don't always work great together with multi-threading, don't count on them being thread-safe. It could possibly be some issue where you call such a function from multiple threads, without mutex protection. Maybe post the code to the thread callback functions.

Comment: @Lundin
I appended the code running in the file deletion thread to the original question.
The used functions are:
- fopen
- fwrite
- fflush
- fclose
- open
- close
- mmap
- munmap
- stat
- remove

Comment: What is `logging`? If it isn't thread-safe, then that could be a problem.

Comment: @Lundin
logging is a wrapper for fprintf, which goes to stdout and stderr in this case. C11 does not require it to be thread save, but POSIX does. It is a very good question, but during normal runtime logging is used extensively and never gives problems (even in the presence of multiple threads). Or are there any known glibc bugs in fprintf?

Comment: I'm hardly an expert on these things, so I'm not the right person to answer. It might be something worth investigating though.