# Reader Writer Problem With Writer Priority Problem

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I came across this problem as I am learning more about operating systems. In my code, I've tried making the reader having priority and it worked, so next I modified it a bit to make the writer have the priority. When I ran the code, the output was exactly the same and it seemed like the writer did not have the priority. Here is the code with comments. I am not sure what I've done wrong, since I modified a lot of the code but the output remains the same if I did not change it at all.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
This program provides a possible solution for first readers writers problem using mutex and semaphore.
I have used 10 readers and 5 producers to demonstrate the solution. You can always play with these values.
*/

// Semaphore initialization for writer and reader 
sem_t wrt;
sem_t rd;

// Mutex 1 blocks other readers, mutex 2 blocks other writers
pthread_mutex_t mutex1;
pthread_mutex_t mutex2;

// Value the writer is changing, we are simply multiplying this value by 2
int cnt = 2;

int numreader = 0;
int numwriter = 0;

void *writer(void *wno)
{   
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex2);
    numwriter++;
    if(numwriter == 1){
        sem_wait(&rd);      
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex2);
    sem_wait(&wrt); 

    // Writing Section
    cnt = cnt*2;
    printf("Writer %d modified cnt to %d\n",(*((int *)wno)),cnt);

    sem_post(&wrt);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex2);
    numwriter--;
    if(numwriter == 0){
        sem_post(&rd);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex2); 

}
void *reader(void *rno)
{   
    sem_wait(&rd);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
    numreader++;
    if(numreader == 1){
        sem_wait(&wrt);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
    sem_post(&rd); 

    // Reading Section
    printf("Reader %d: read cnt as %d\n",*((int *)rno),cnt);

    
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
    numreader--;
    if(numreader == 0){
        sem_post(&wrt);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1); 
}

int main()
{   

    pthread_t read[10],write[5];
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex1, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex2, NULL);
    sem_init(&wrt,0,1);
    sem_init(&rd,0,1);

    int a[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}; //Just used for numbering the writer and reader

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        pthread_create(&write[i], NULL, (void *)writer, (void *)&a[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        pthread_create(&read[i], NULL, (void *)reader, (void *)&a[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        pthread_join(write[i], NULL);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        pthread_join(read[i], NULL);
    }

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex1);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex2);
    sem_destroy(&wrt);
    sem_destroy(&rd);

    return 0;
    
}
```

Output (for both is the same. I think if writer had priority it will change first, then will be read):
[image]

Comment: Please provide the output and explain why you think it is wrong.

Comment: @kaylum added in the main post.

Comment: there is no link between mutex&semaphore with 'priority'. When your threads can have the hand they get it, that is all.

Comment: @kaylum Makes sense, how do I go about with the linking?

Comment: First what is *really* your goal ? Out of that a good way to exchange data between producer(s) and consumer(s) is to use queue(s), and active waiting is not a good way

Comment: @bruno I just want the writer to be able to write data first and then the reader to be able to read it in order to implement the reader-writer problem

Comment: so as I said use queue, implement it in the worst case

Comment: @bruno I'll do that in a bit, for now I want to know how to fix this particular code

Comment: It’s an unusual problem if readers don’t block writers, but do block other readers. Are they reading and writing different data? Maybe there’s a better approach.

Comment: @Davislor im trying to implement the reader-writer problem with writer having priorirty

Comment: @worknovel But in the classic reader-writer problem, don’t readers block writers, and not each other? Maybe a reader-writer lock, a wait-free list, an atomic variable with producer-consumer memory ordering?

Comment: @Davislor Forgive me as i am entirely new to this topic, but the reason to give writer priority is as to not starve them

Comment: @worknovel Yes, but it’s not clear to me that you need mutexes at all. Semaphore operations are already atomic without locking, and there are lock-free atomicoperations on most CPUs. The increment-and-test-for-1 sequence could, for example, be an atomic compare-and-swap.

Comment: @Davislor alright, I can change them to become semaphores but the output remains

Comment: Well, you’re not really giving writers priority. A semaphore is probably not the synchronization primitive you really want here, but even with one, you could for example have readers `sem_getvalue()` and back off, idle-waiting for the writers instead of getting in line before them.

Comment: You also might want to allow any number of readers to read without blocking each other.

Comment: [This also looks like a similar question, although not a duplicate.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666610/how-to-give-priority-to-privileged-thread-in-mutex-locking)

Comment: in the thread function: `reader()` AND `writer()` just running off the end of the function is not correct.  Your compiler should have told you about this problem.  suggest, before the closing brace, insert: `pthread_exit( NULL );`

Answer (score 0):

#### Alternative Semantics

Much of what you want to do can probably be accomplished with less overhead.  For example, in the classic reader-writer problem, readers shouldn’t need to block other readers.

You might be able to replace the reader-writer pattern with a publisher-consumer pattern that manages pointers to blocks of data with acquire-consume memory ordering.  You only need locking at all if one thread needs to update the same block of memory after it was originally written.

POSIX and Linux have an implementation of reader-writer locks in the system library, which were designed to avoid starvation.  This is most likely the high-level construct you want.

If you still want to implement your own, one implementation would use a count of current readers, a count of pending writers and a flag that indicates whether a write is in progress.  It packs all these values into an atomic bitfield that it updates with a compare-and-swap.

Reader threads would retrieve the value, check whether there are any starving writers waiting, and if not, increment the count of readers.  If there are writers, it backs off (perhaps spinning and yielding the CPU, perhaps sleeping on a condition variable). If there is a write in progress, it waits for that to complete.  If it sees only other reads in progress, it goes ahead.

Writer threads would check if there are any reads or writes in progress.  If so, they increment the count of waiting writers, and wait.  If not, they set the write-in-progress bit and proceed.

Packing all these fields into the same atomic bitfield guarantees that no thread will think it’s safe to use the buffer while another thread thinks it’s safe to write: if two threads try to update the state at the same time, one will always fail.

#### If You Stick With Semaphores

You can still have reader threads check `sem_getvalue()` on the writer semaphore, and back off if they see any starved writers are waiting.  One method would be to wait on a condition variable that threads signal when they are done with the buffer.  A reader that sees that it holds the mutex while writers are waiting can try to wake up one writer thread and go back to sleep, and a reader that sees only other readers are waiting can wake up a reader, which will wake up the next reader, and so on.